# Compactness of the sum of line segments

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $A\subset(0,\infty)$. Now $X(A)\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ will be a sum of closed intervals connecting points $(0,-1)$ and $(a,\frac{1}{a})$, $a\in A$.

I am asked to prove $X(A)$ is compact $\iff A$ is compact $\iff X(A)$ is closed. The topology is natural.

I find it very hard to write anything beside saying it's obvious. How would you go from talking about line segments to talking about points?

Comment: It looks like you are saying $I(a,b) =[a,b]$ (or $[b,a]$ if $b<a$). So what does the notation $I((-1,0),(a,\frac1a))$ mean? The arguments of $I$ are supposed to be elements of $\mathbb R$, but you are using intervals?

Comment: I'll rephrase it. Of course what I mean is closed intervals on two dimensional plane.

Comment: Ah, I see now, sorry for being so dense. So this space is a sort of planar fan with ramification point $(-1,0)$. Or perhaps star-shaped region is more apt since $A$ could contain an interval.

Answer (score 1):

Let me organize things a bit for you so it's clear what you have to do:

It's easy to see that $A$ is bounded $\iff$ $X(A)$ is bounded. Therefore you have prove only that $X(A)$ is closed $\iff$ $A$ is closed and $X(A)$ is closed $\implies$ $A$ is bounded.

Clearly $X(A)$ is closed $\implies$ $A$ is closed because $A$ is an intersection of $X(A)$ with a closed set (which one?).

The last implication can be proven by taking the contrapositive: $A$ is unbounded $\implies$ $X(A)$ is not closed, do you see this?

What remains is $A$ closed $\implies$ $X(A)$ closed, can you prove that?

Comment: So basically it is all more or less obvious, mind the $A$ closed $\iff$ $X(A)$ closed part. And actually, no, I don't see the --> implication. I suppose I don't need to use the definition of a closed set here. Or do I?

Comment: @Jules If it's obvious, you should be able to prove it. Can you actually formally prove any of the 4 nontrivial implications? (there are 6 to prove in total, but $X(A)$ bounded $\implies$ $A$ bounded and $X(A)$ compact $\implies$ $X(A)$ closed are trivial). Also draw a picture, then you should be able to see the implication you mention (the one with unbounded $A$ if I undestand you correctly)

Comment: Shhhh, that's challenging. I indeed see $A$ is unbounded ⟹ $X(A)$ is not closed, but definitely can't prove that (I'd just say it's the way it is). I also find $A$ bounded ⟹ $X(A)$ bounded trival. Then I think I can prove $X(A)$ is closed ⟹ $A$ is closed, but as I said don't see the reverse.

Comment: @Jules Well, then we need some definitions. In this answer I regard $\mathbb R^2$ as a metric space and definitions are as follows: Bounded means there's $r>0$ such that for all $a,b$ in the set $d(a,b)\le r$. Closed means if $B(x,1/n)$ contains a point in the set for all $n$, then $x$ is in the set too. E.g. in the implication you definitely can't prove, try to find a point which doesn't satisfy this.